# Difference between TLFTextField/TextArea/TextField in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Can someone explain me what is the difference between these three types of Text class in AS3? I'm using them right now and I don't know which is better to my purposes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLFTextField is an allround textfield. I supports allot of textfeatures including asian from right to left and from top to bottom lines. You can also use it to wrap text around objects or images. Or let text flow from 1 block into another block. Just to sum up: Allot of features.

The "old" TextField is just the "simple" input field (can also be used as password box) and textarea is just plain text. (non editable field)